# How to alter multiple table with one mysqli_query query using PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to add some columns to all tables with one query. In phpmyadmin in db I can add it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `Table1` ADD `clm1` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `id`;

ALTER TABLE `Table2` ADD `clm1` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `id`;
```

In phpyMyAdmin I could add to these tables with one query. However, in PHP when I write this

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "Alter TABLE `Table1` ADD `clm1` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `id`; Alter TABLE `Table2` ADD `clm1` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `id`");
```

It is not working. Is there any way to do it with one query?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Any errors? Only one column migrated? No columns migrated?

Comment: If they are two separate statements, you must execute them separately. If it's the same table then you can combine it into one.

Comment: `Is there any way to do it with one query?`...no, but it's not necessary. Just run mysqli_query twice. Is that a problem? It shouldn't be.

Comment: P.S. I don't think the nominated duplicate is applicable because it's talking about changing multiple columns on one table. That can be done in one SQL statement. But in your case you're altering different tables so it has to be done with multiple statements. And mysqli_query can only execute one SQL statement at a time. There _is_ a mysqli_multi_query function you can use to execute multiple SQL statements from one PHP command, but use it with care because you can't use parameterisation with it, so only use it for fixed queries which don't incorporate any user input values.

Comment: Well there is `mysqli_multi_query()` but its a whole lot more pain to get things right. Simply do it in 2 seperate queries. Also I am not sure (I never did it) if DDL will work through it

Comment: Guys you disappointed me( I have  analytic dashboard and I was thinking to add feature for altering tables from dashboard. Now I think it is better to alter them in DB with  SQL query

Comment: Why? None of this is _difficult_, it's just the way things are.

Comment: I know how to implement them seperately. Idk, although we rarely alter tables so maybe it is not that bad altering them saperately

Comment: Fundamentally though it's generally very rare than an application needs to alter its own database. Doing that often indicates a design flaw in the schema. Not always, but in most cases.

Comment: If you need to change 50 tables from within your code it sounds like a bad design. Why do you need to change so many tables?

Comment: @Dharman We need to know how long a site visitor stayed in each site and to store this data I need to add one column to each table

Comment: That would be a one-time activity done by the developer as a migration. Adding the data is just adding a new row. Your application shouldn't change the database structure.

Comment: You are right.  I meant columns not rows. I will leave like that probably. Thank you